# creating a program that calculates the number of days delegated to heating and cooling homes based on temperature on certain days

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-3.8

I have created a program that calculates the number of days delegated to heating and cooling  homes based on temperature on certain days.  If the temp>80 it is delegated as a cooling day and if the temp<60 delegated as a heating.  I have created a while loop to loop through and ask for the temp for each day with a corresponding "stop" value to stop entering days.  After this the program is supposed to print the total amount of heat and cool days but something in my code is broke where it is not able to decipher the different days and each time it just comes up as 0 for each.

```
def main():
    day = 1
    C_days = 0
    H_days = 0
    done = False
    while not done:
        temp = input("Please enter the average temperature for day " + str(day) + " or stop to end: ")
        if temp.lower() != "stop" and temp.lower() != "s":
            temp = eval(temp)
            if temp > 80:
                C_days += temp-80
            elif temp < 60:
                H_days += 60-temp
            day += 1
        else:
            done = True
    print("The number of heating-degree days: ", H_days)
    print("The number of cooling-degree days: ", C_days)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this

```py
def main():
    day = 1
    C_days = 0
    H_days = 0
    done = False
    while not done:
        temp = input("Please enter the average temperature for day " + str(day) + " or stop to end: ")
        #checks if it's supposed to stop or not
        if temp.lower() != "stop" and temp.lower() != "s":
            temp = eval(temp)
            if temp > 80:
                #here is a change, since you want the total number of days,
                #you just have to add one to the cooling days if it's more than 80
                C_days = C_days + 1
            elif temp < 60:
                #and here is a change, since you want the total number of days,
                #you just have to add one to the heating days if it's more than 80
                H_days = H_days + 1
            day += 1
        else:
            done = True
    print("The number of heating-degree days: ", H_days)
    print("The number of cooling-degree days: ", C_days)
main()
```

Comment: I think it would help if you described why your code works and highlight the differences

Comment: Sorry about that, I commented my code to describe what happens in the differences